# Which one of the following sentence is correct

Tags: prepositions

1. There are  a number of newspapers in Kannada and English.
2. There are a number of newspapers of Kannada and English

Comment: What exactly is Kannada? Is it some kind of place? And what do you mean by English? The English language? You really need to explain which is which in there. Otherwise, it's very hard to tell what exactly you're trying to say with those two sentences.

Comment: Kannada and English both are languages

Answer (score 2):

If we're talking about spoken languages, then we say that something such as a book or a newspaper is in English or in French or in Spanish or what have you. For example:

> Since I'm studying French, I would prefer to read daily news in French rather than in English.

When you say that something is written in a particular language, expressions like *a book of English* or *a newspaper of English* would sound very strange and in certain situations would actually mean something completely different. A book of English, for instance, would probably mean something like a book about English or a book pertaining to English, but not necessarily a book that has been written using the English language.

So, of the two, only your first sentence is correct.